# How to make standalone app from ejected expo project

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, expo

everyone.
I have ejected expo project.
It works well on local.
To make standalone app, I execute the command "expo publish" and then make the apk file from android studio.
And install this apk file on android phone. 
But app wasn't run and show following screen:

Screenshot when expo app running
[image: screenshot when expo app running]

Then how can I build standalone app from ejected expo project.

I'm very happy to hear your advance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to solve your problem. However, I'd recommend that you use `expo build:android`, then you can download the APK from the provided link when the build is done.